# How to select and disable checkbox if another td displays a specific text

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm new to Jquery and would really appreciate any help.

My table has many rows with some  as Error:

```
        <td>
            Error:
           <input name="[0].ValidationResult" type="hidden" value="Error:" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isChecked field is required." name="[0].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
        </td>
```

I would like to figure out to disable the checkboxes in the same row as the  Error:

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic be done on the server, but if for some reason you need to do it with javascript:

```
$(':hidden[value="Error:"]')
    .closest('tr')
    .find('td :checkbox')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .attr('checked', 'checked');
```

As pointed out in the comments section if you are using jQuery 1.6+ the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method should be used instead of `.attr`:

```
$(':hidden[value="Error:"]')
    .closest('tr')
    .find('td :checkbox')
    .prop('disabled', true)
    .prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: IMO While `.attr()` might be good to retrieve `titles` the newborn `.prop()` might be correct. (One eye to the future!)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, good point. I have updated my answer to take it into account. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Darin...The server I have logic to set the checkbox to false if error is caught. However the user can still select/check it in the GUI. I wasn't sure if there was a way to disable it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to give the cells which contains an error a specific class, and use that class in the jQuery selector.

```
<td class="errorTd>
     Error:
     <input name="[0].ValidationResult" type="hidden" value="Error:" />
</td>

<td>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The isChecked field is required." name="[0].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
</td>
```

Now you can disable inputs in cells with class="errorTd" like this:

```
$('.errorTd input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```